# How to import Pull Requests history from one ADO project to another ADO project?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a scenario where the project needs to be moved from one Azure DevOps organization to another Azure DevOps organization. The project consists of several code repositories, pull requests(linked with the work items) and Azure Pipeline history.

I could move the Azure repos with all existing branches and commit history successfully but Pull requests are not copied. Though I can see the Merge commit with the Pull request ID and the description but it doesn't have the other metadata i.e. reviewer, comments and Build history etc.

I tried to play around with the ADO Rest APIs:
[Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#just-completed-pull-requests)

It returns all the completed Pull requests, but same can't be imported in the new project.

Has anyone found any solution for this?

Comment: You can't. It's not possible.

Comment: @DanielMann : I read some of your previous comments and answer. Was hoping that Microsoft added some feature now.

Comment: @Nishu Tayal, have you created a feature request? If you have, it's suggested that you could share with us. So that others wanting the same function can submit a vote and follow it. Thanks.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT : Sure, Here is the feature request link : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Copy-the-closed-pull-requests-from-one-p/10562428

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure DevOps does not support importing Pull Requests history from one project to another by default. If you want such a feature, it's recommended that you could submit a feature request on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.

Comment: @Nishu Tayal, thanks for sharing the feature request https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Copy-the-closed-pull-requests-from-one-p/10562428 with us. To let others who want the same feature as you know there isn't such a default feature more clearly and can follow on the feature request, it's suggested that you could accept the answer. Thanks.